# I can't move sprites in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

It's the first time I create a game with pygame and I find a logical error. This game consist in a sort of puzzle and to play it you have to click to the piece of puzzle then click on the area where you want it to move. When I try to run my code, sprites doesn't move. I tried to modify the function move(), but it didn't change anything. When I run the program and I selected and move the pieces of puzzle of the game they are drawing again by the computer but in the same position. They aren't moving at the coordinates that I write in the code.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
import os
width = 1100
hight = 700
square1 = (240, 45) 
square2 = (25, 55)
square3 = (25, 245)
square4 = (248, 245)
coords1 = [800, 50]
coords2 = [550, 50]
coords3 = [550, 250]
coords4 = [810, 250]

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, hight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hidden Boys')

background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill((250, 250, 250))

class Puzzle_piece(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, image_file, location):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.counter = 0
    self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location
    self.state = "still"
    self.area = screen.get_rect()
    self.angle = 0
    self.movepos = [0, 0]

  def updates(self, position):
    self.rect = position

  def move(self):
      screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

  def rotate_right(self):
      self.angle += -90
      self.image = pg.transform.rotozoom(self.orig_image, self.angle, 1)
      self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)

class Frame(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, image_file = None, location = None, dim = screen, color = (250, 250, 250)):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  #call Sprite initializer
    if image_file and location != None :
      self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
      self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
      self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location
    self.frame = pygame.Surface(dim.get_size())
    self.frame = self.frame.convert()
    self.frame.fill(color)

def create_text(dim, blitted, color = (0, 0, 0), font = "", msg = "", position = (width, hight), alias = True):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(font, dim)
    text = font.render(msg, alias, color)
    textpos = text.get_rect()
    textpos.center = position
    blitted.blit(text, textpos)


def create_frames(name = "frame0", dim = screen, color = (250, 250, 250), image ="" ):
  name = pygame.Surface(dim.get_size())
  name = name.convert()
  name.fill(color)
  return name, img

def blit_frames(frame, coords = (0, 0), image = None, image_rect = None):
  if image and image_rect != None :
    frame.blit(image, image_rect)
  screen.blit(frame, coords)
  pygame.display.update()
  pygame.display.flip()

def draw_sprites(sprites, frame, group):
  for x in range(len(sprites)):
    screen.blit(frame, sprites[x].rect, sprites[x].rect)
    sprites[x].image = pygame.transform.scale(sprites[x].image, (272, 272))
  group.update()
  group.draw(screen)
  pygame.display.flip()

background = Frame()
Frame1 = Frame("images\\field1.png", [-20, 0])
Piece1 = Puzzle_piece("images\\piece11.png", coords1)
Piece2 = Puzzle_piece("images\\piece21.png", coords2)
Piece3 = Puzzle_piece("images\\piece31.png", coords3)
Piece4 = Puzzle_piece("images\\piece41.png", coords4)
sprites_group = [Piece1, Piece2, Piece3, Piece4]
Piece_sprites = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain(sprites_group)

create_text(font = "squared_display", dim = 120, msg = "HIDDEN BOYS", position = (width/2, hight/4), blitted = background.frame)
create_text(font = "squared_display", dim = 50, msg = "Click to start", position = (width/2, hight/2), blitted = background.frame)

def move_pieces(piece):
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if pygame.mouse.get_pos() in square1:
      piece.updates(square1)
      piece.move()
    if pygame.mouse.get_pos() in square2:
      piece.updates(square2)
      piece.move()
    if pygame.mouse.get_pos() in square3:
      piece.updates(square3)
      piece.move()
    if pygame.mouse.get_pos() in square4:
      piece.updates(square4)
      piece.move()


screen.blit(background.frame, (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()

def main():
  clock = pygame.time.Clock()

  while True:
    frame = 0
    counter = 0
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == QUIT:
        return

      if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if frame == 0:
          blit_frames(Frame1.frame, Frame1.rect, image = Frame1.image, image_rect = Frame1.rect)
          draw_sprites(sprites_group, Frame1.frame, Piece_sprites)
          frame += 1
        elif frame == 1:
          if pygame.mouse.get_pos() in coords1:
            Piece1.state = "selected"
            Piece1.counter += 1
            move_pieces(Piece1)

          if pygame.mouse.get_pos() in coords2:
            Piece2.state = "selected"
            Piece2.counter += 1
            move_pieces(Piece2)

          if pygame.mouse.get_pos() in coords3:
            Piece3.state = "selected"
            Piece3.counter += 1
            move_pieces(Piece3)

          if pygame.mouse.get_pos() in coords4:
            Piece4.state = "selected"
            Piece4.counter += 1
            move_pieces(Piece4)

      if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        if pygame.mouse.get_pos() in coords1 or coords2 or coords3 or coords4:
          if Piece1.counter % 2 != 0:
            Piece1.state = "unselected"
          if Piece2.counter % 2 != 0:
            Piece2.state = "unselected"
          if Piece3.counter % 2 != 0:
            Piece3.state = "unselected"
          if Piece4.counter % 2 != 0:
            Piece4.state = "unselected"
      pygame.display.update()
      pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please _do not_ use the edit feature to add any sort of pleading. Remember that it is volunteers who help here, and they will not be hurried by deadlines. Read the link I have offered to understand that the community feels strongly about this. In any case, such commentary will be irrelevant after your deadline, and ought to be removed for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Your `updates` method assigns the the tuple `position` to the rect object. Instead, try:

```
def updates(self, position):
    self.rect.x, self.rect.y = position
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for you answer, but I tried your code and it didn't work

Comment: @Giovanni: when responding to an answer here, remember that you are the eyes and ears on the problem. A response of "that didn't work" is of no use to your helper, who would have to make an effort to get information from you in order to help further. So, help  FrznBluberries help you: explain, in detail, **how it did not work**. Did you get an error? Did you get something in a log file? Could you do some debugging, perhaps? What specific information can you offer readers that will help them?